# Trying to update an attribute that was saved with null value with another value in a DynamoDB table using CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, crud-repository

I've saved an object in DynamoDB using SpringBoot CrudRepository. It has some attributes with null value ("myAttribute": null) and others with values ("otherAttribute": "aValue").

I have a method to update the object, where I search by id, update it and then, save it again.

If I update an attribute that has a value, it gets updated. But If I put a value to the ones that has null, they don't get updated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamoDB handles null value as a distinct data type. So I'll make an assumption here that you are setting a string or object type to Null, in which case the Mapper (assumption) is not saving the value as it drops null values. If it's a string, one thing you can do is set the value to `"NULL"` for example.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html

Comment: The attribute is a String annotated with @DynamoDBAttributre. We had a batch of insertions with this value as null. What I'm trying to do right now is update them with an actual String (let's say "aValue"). Thing is that after doing the save again with the object updated, this particular attribute is not updated.

Comment: Do you get a status code 200 returned?

Comment: Yeap. Also, if I save a new object with a value in this attribute, after that I can update it without any issues.

Comment: Can you enable wire logging in your application and have a look at the payload being sent to DynamoDB?

Comment: I don't have access to do that. But trying to think about what you commented. If it was set up as NULL type when it was created, by retrieving it, putting a value and then save it again, should this change be considered?

Comment: Which client do you use, Mapper or Enhanced or a low level client? If your update is trying to save a string as a value, but that attribute name is already being used for Null, then it will throw an exception.

Comment: I'm using the default client from aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:1.11.443

Comment: Yea so that's your issue, the value is a Null type in DynamoDB then you're trying to make it a string also. You'd need to do a remove and set in your update item.

Comment: Do you mean there is a way to remove the attribute and then add it with the right data type and value? If that's the case, how would you do that?

Comment: Using 2 updateItemSpecs, one with "remove myAttribute" and then the second with "set myAttribute = theRightValue" for each item maybe?

Comment: You can achieve both in a single operations. Let me know if you have difficulties and I'll share an example.

Comment: I tried this way and it seems to work, but if you have a simpler example, it'll be great. Thanks for all your help!